# Displaying Forms With Strings

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, forms, boolean

How do I get all messages before showing a form, and display this form one by one?

First of all, I have a program that gets an entry if the "Client" is already checked out or if a reservation of a client has already expired.  With this method, I will get their transaction number and client number in put their infos in a form and display it.  Notice that I have a different form for EXPIRED RESERVATION and CHECK OUT

Can someone check my program?  Here is my code for getting the client if his/her check in has expired.

```
Public Sub computeRemainingDaysForCheckedIns()

    Dim computedDays As Integer
    Dim dateNow As Date = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    Try
        mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection(con)
        mysqlconn.Open()
        query = "select TransactionNumber, ClientNumber, DATEDIFF(dateout,curdate()) as 'ComputedDays' from dbo_transactions where ClientStatus = 'Checked In'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If rd.HasRows Then
            'hasRows ibig sabhin mayLAMAN ung table
            While rd.Read
                computedDays = rd.GetString("ComputedDays")
                'Console.WriteLine(computedDays)
                If computedDays > 0 Then
                    getTransactionNumber = ""
                    getClientNumber = ""
                ElseIf computedDays < 0 Then

                    getTransactionNumber = rd.GetString("TransactionNumber")
                    getClientNumber = rd.GetString("ClientNumber")

                    iTitle = "CHECK OUT CLIENT."
                    iMessage.AppendLine("* Client: " & getClientNumber & ", Transaction: " & getTransactionNumber & " *")
                    isCNotifShowed = True
                End If

            End While
            'notificationFormC.Show()
        Else
            'no data
        End If
        mysqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        isCNotifShowed = False
        MsgBox("Something Went Wrong!" & vbNewLine &
               ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub computeRemainingDaysForReservations()

    Dim computedDays As Integer

    Try
        mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection(con)
        mysqlconn.Open()
        query = "Select TransactionNumber, ClientNumber, DATEDIFF(DateIn, CURDATE()) as 'ComputedDays' from dbo_transactions where ClientStatus = 'Reserved'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If rd.HasRows Then
            'hasRows ibig sabhin mayLAMAN ung table
            While rd.Read
                computedDays = rd.GetString("ComputedDays")
                'Console.WriteLine(computedDays)
                If computedDays > 0 Then
                    getTransactionNumber = ""
                    getClientNumber = ""
                ElseIf computedDays <= 0 Then
                    getTransactionNumber = rd.GetString("TransactionNumber")
                    getClientNumber = rd.GetString("ClientNumber")

                    iiTitle = "RESERVATION IS ALREADY EXPIRED."
                    iiMessage.AppendLine("* " & getClientNumber & ", Transaction: " & getTransactionNumber & " *")
                    isRNotifShowed = True
                End If

            End While
        Else
            'no data
        End If
        rd.Close()
        mysqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        isRNotifShowed = False
        MsgBox("Something Went Wrong!" & vbNewLine &
               ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

then for displaying the client using a form

```
Private Sub RepeatProcess()
    computeRemainingDaysForReservations()
    computeRemainingDaysForCheckedIns()

    If iMessage.Length <> 0 Then

    ElseIf iiMessage.Length <> 0 Then

    End If

    'If isCNotifShowed = True Then
    'notificationFormC.Show()
    'ElseIf isRNotifShowed = True Then
    ' notificationFormR.Show()
    'Else
    'End If

End Sub

Private Sub timerTask_Tick_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerTask.Tick
    tCount += 1
    If tCount = tSecs Then
        Call RepeatProcess()
        tCount = 0                     'reset
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code in your question rather than linking to an image

Comment: i created a link for my codes.

Comment: No - post your code on this site; if PasteBin deletes your code then how can anyone reference it in the future?

Comment: @paul i already posted my code. can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is not the best way of doing this. Opening a new form/pop-up/whatever for every booking that is out of date could potentially suck up all of your resources.

I would recommend that you display a `GridView`, `DataGrid`, `ListView` or similar (we're still chiselling stone tablets out in VS2008, so I'm not sure what extremes of technology there are in more recent versions!). The code behind could be written to highlight the problem records in a different colour so that they are more obvious.

To do this you'd simply need to create a DataSource on your form with the relevant query(ies) then display the results in a the appropriate data enabled grid.